# How can I set client connection limit for Redis in .net application?

Tags: redis, session-state, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I don't want to allow a new client connection when the connection limit reached 10.

Is there any way to set client connection limit in redis through web.config file?

Comment: Can you clarify what do you want to do and why? It's not clear. You want to set the limit server-side or client-side?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually write a rate limiter using redis itself, see [Introduction to rate limiting with Redis](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/introduction-to-rate-limiting-with-redis/155)